# Ghostscript | Unrecoverable Error, exit code 1

Tags: php, apache, debian, ghostscript

I have a shell script that I've been using to merge PDFs, and prior to today, it seems to have been working fine.

Now when I run, I get the message:
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

It produces a blank PDF instead of the merged PDF. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$pdf1 = "file_1.pdf";
$pdf2 = "file_2.pdf";


$fileArray= array($pdf1,$pdf2);


$datadir = "/usr/pdf_merge/merged";
$outputName = $datadir."merged_new.pdf";

$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";
//Add each pdf file to the end of the command
foreach($fileArray as $file) {
    $cmd .= $file." ";
}
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I'm running Apache with Debian.

Thanks

Comment: what files do you combine ? does any file of the files contain a space ?

Comment: `$datadir` is not missing slash at the end? Try to use realpath function for output path.

Comment: @DiogoAlves You're right it did need a slash, but that didn't solve the overall issue

Comment: Firstly (sorry to keep repeating this) you aren't 'merging' PDF files. You are creating a new PDF file which should appear identical to the input. The internal content of the PDF file will be different to its inputs though. You haven't supplied the files, so we can't try it ourselves, you haven't supplied the back channel output from Ghostscript, **and** you are using -q which reduces the amount of information the back channel would give, making it less useful. Finally you are using a version of Ghostscript which is.6 years old, you need to upgrade.

Comment: If you supply the files, I'll take a look, the back channel transcript would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

change this `$cmd` into

```
$outputName = "merged_new.pdf";
$cmd = "cd ".$datadir." && gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";"
```