# GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, ghostscript

The following script outputs a Ghostscript error of `GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1` (and produces an empty PDF). Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281608/ghostscript-unrecoverable-error-exit-code-1), I am running on Windows10. Per @KJ's answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588946/merge-pdfs-in-ghostscript-with-python-list-of-unc-paths) last week (as well as [Ghostscript docs](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Finding_files)), I've switched up how I use paths, so I'm fairly certain paths are not the issue. I have tried placing quotes around the paths, as well as without (see `inputPDFsList`); Both methods produce the error above.

What am I doing wrong?  Happy to include PDFs if needed.

Here is the script, and the full output (print statements, etc.) follows:

```
import subprocess
import time

yyyymmdd_hhmmss = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S')
print("Time stamp: " + yyyymmdd_hhmmss)

# inputPDFsList = [f"//someNetwork/T/Tools/single_page_pdfs/Page_{i}.pdf" for i in range(1,4)] ### With quotes around paths
inputPDFsList = [f"'//someNetwork/T/Tools/single_page_pdfs/Page_{i}.pdf'" for i in range(1,4)] ### Without quotes

outputPDF_Path = f"//someNetwork/T/Tools/CompilationPDF_{yyyymmdd_hhmmss}.pdf"

inputPagesAsStr = " ".join(inputPDFsList)
print("Input-Pages as a string:")
print(inputPagesAsStr)

print("Output-PDF path:")
print(outputPDF_Path)

print("Begin SubProcess...")
subprocess.Popen([
        '//someNetwork/T/Tools/Ghostscript_Tools/GS_Install/gs9.54.0/bin/gswin64c',
        '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', 
        '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4',
        '-dNOPAUSE',
        '-dBATCH',
        '-dQUIET',
        '-dDOPDFMARKS',
        "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress",
        "-sPageList=1",
        f"-sOutputFile={outputPDF_Path}",###  Or ???   f'-o "{outputPDF_Path}"',
        inputPagesAsStr
        ], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print("Subprocess complete")
```

Output:

```
Time stamp: 2021_10_22__16_36_08
Input-Pages as a string:
'//someNetwork/T/Tools/single_page_pdfs/Page_1.pdf' '//someNetwork/T/Tools/single_page_pdfs/Page_2.pdf' '//someNetwork/T/Tools/single_page_pdfs/Page_3.pdf'
Output-PDF path:
//someNetwork/T/Tools/CompilationPDF_2021_10_22__16_36_08.pdf
Begin SubProcess...
Subprocess complete

GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: The problem may have nothing to do with Python. Try running Ghostscript manually on a test file.